# PHP - Session variables modification

Tags: php, session, var

I have an unexpected problem in my website project. It's kind of weird situation, so I decided to ask you guys.

First let me explain what I want to achieve.

I'm creating a website with login/register system and have a var that uses session to check if user is logged in. Because I have a lot of code I removed temporarily the whole code and placed new code with just some basic operations on session variables. It turned out that the code is still not working. So it has to be some basic stuff (?). Let me show you:

```
//Index.php
session_start();
<a href='setvar.php'>Set Vars</a>
<a href='showvar.php'>Show Vars</a>
<a href='deletevar.php'>Delete Vars</a>
<a href='only_if_var_is_not_set.php'>Var Is Not Set</a>

//Set Var
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = 1;
header("Location: index.php");

//Show Var
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['var'])) echo 'SESSION VAR IS SET';

//Delete Var
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
header("Location: index.php");

//Only If Var Is Not Set
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['var'])) header("Location index.php");
```

Before setting anything i can smoothly go to page Only If Var Is Set. The thing is that when I go to page Set Var and then to Show Var i have my communicate 'SESSION VAR IS SET', but when I go to Delete Var and then try to enter Only If Var Is Not Set it redirects me to index.php and on Show Var i can't see my var existing... Anybody knows what may be the reason for that?

Somebody mentioned to check session_id. There interesting things are happening also. Session Id is the same on every page but when I delete my session and vars it changes on index.php and logout page but then after refreshing it returns to the previous value...
Waiting for your advices.
Thanks a lot.
John.

Comment: you only need one `session_start()` at the top

Comment: @Dave these are multiple files.

Comment: then pop one into index.php as well

Comment: Your debugging strategy is .. peculiar. Can you find something more robust than a misspelled location redirect? Like, print the contents of the session and the session_id.

Comment: already did. thanks ;) . bit still no result.

Comment: do you have cookies off for everything?

Comment: Be consistent with your wording, `<a href='only_if_var_is_not_set.php'>Var Is Set</a>` makes trying to read, very difficult.

Comment: not sure that `$_SESSION = array();` is valid.  `session_unset();` may be better... though redundant after the destroy

Comment: @BrettSantore just wanted to mark that this page is checking the var

Comment: can you drop a little `if(!session_start()){ echo "HELP"; }` to ensure you don't have an issue with sessions in general?

Comment: looks like an issue with sessions is alright.

Comment: still nothing happened....

Answer (score 0):

check `session.save_path` and make sure you have permissions (in your PHP.INI file)

Comment: Some info on permissions can be found here if needed  http://serverfault.com/questions/70634/what-permissions-ownership-to-set-on-php-sessions-folder-when-running-fastcgi